# Unable to build the jar with maven-jar-plugin

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-jar-plugin

I am using maven-compiler-plugin 3.1  When I try to do 'Run As---> Maven install', I am getting the following error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) on project test-tom: Error assembling JAR: For artifact {org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.
```

Comment: Share your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Use the appropriate parent and of Spring Boot as stated in the docs and run a `mvn clean package` on command line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluded the tomcat depends from spring boot starter

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```